# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.Vector.size()' on a null object reference after using proguard

Tags: java, android, proguard, assets

In my app I called JSON data from txt file, named country_code.txt.
I called that file to input stream (in Register1PhoneAndPassword) :

```
       try {
            is = getActivity().getAssets().open("country_code.txt");
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            countryCodes = gson.fromJson(StringUtil.ConvertInputStreamToString(is), CountryCodes.class);
            is.close();
            myCountries = countryCodes.getCountryCodeModelList();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        adapter = new CountryCodeAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.my_item_countrycode_item, myCountries);
```

and I called certain file using this :

```
int location = countryCodes.getCountryPosition("+62");
```

This is CountryCodes Class :

```
public class CountryCodes {

    public Vector<CountyCodeModel> data;
    public String[] name;

    public int getCountryPosition(String dial_code) {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
            if (dial_code.equalsIgnoreCase(data.get(i).dial_code))
                return i;
        return -1;
    }

    public ArrayList<CountyCodeModel> getCountryCodeModelList() {
        ArrayList<CountyCodeModel> myCountries = new ArrayList<CountyCodeModel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            myCountries.add(data.get(i));
        }
        return myCountries;
    }

    public String getDialCode(int location) {
        return data.get(location).dial_code;
    }

    public class CountyCodeModel {
        public String name;
        public String dial_code;
        public String code;
    }
}
```

At first, all is working well, but after I use proguard with this rules :

```
-dontwarn org.joda.convert.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-keep class org.joda.time.** { *; }
-keep interface org.joda.time.** { *; }
-keep public class * extends *
-keep public class * implements LinphoneCoreListener
-keep interface * { *; }
-keep class org.linphone.** { *; }
-keep class com.marlinmedia.linphone.** {*; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>; }
-keep class **.R$*
-keep class *.R
```

This error is appear :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   java.util.Vector.size()' on a null object reference
>
> ```
>    at com.marlinmedia.dvirna.model.CountryCodes.getCountryPosition()
>
>    at com.marlinmedia.dvirna.fragment.Register1PhoneAndPassword.onCreate()
> ```

Note : I put the country_code.txt file in assets folder

Comment: Mention the rules for gson also http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg

Comment: thanks, it worked...